# Feature request: RSS support

Tags: feature-request, rss

Hi and thank you for this wonderful site, really.

Are you planning to add RSS support to be more reactive?

Answer (score 6):

The situation is even better than Joseph hints add.  There are feeds *all over the place*.  There's one for this specific question, should you so desire.  On any page that you want to follow via RSS, scan down to the bottom and look for the feed symbol.

Comment: there's a feed For specific tags as well

Answer (score 4):

I'm missing a RSS feed for the *newest* questions. The [recent questions feed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/feeds) seems to provide the active questions but not the newest. So it contains a lot of older questions with recent answers. But that answer is hidden while the older question is shown.

Though I like the feature to get informed about any activity, and feeds for tags and specific questions are great, I would like to see the newest questions in another feed additionally.

Comment: Sorry, I was there http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions . I did'nt see there was rss on the index page

Comment: I agree. In fact, a new questions feed is the *only* feed I would subscribe to....

Answer (score 3):

There is RSS support as far as I can see: both the parent site and the meta offer a feed.