# RSS feed for New questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, rss

I have an RSS feed set up for "Recent Questions" from several of the stack exchange websites.  Any time someone edits an old question, it gets added to the RSS feed for "Recent Questions."  **Is there a way to have this set up for only "New Questions"?**

There was a similar comment in [Feature request: RSS support](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281/feature-request-rss-support) a few years ago, but I can't find any updated information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this right now is by tag:

For example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=fonts&sort=newest

You can combine multiple tags as described [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/).

Is that sufficient for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @Anna Lear.  In some sense this works, as one can specify the tag to be NOT something ridiculous, and sort by newest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/-blarg?sort=newest&pagesize=15 

It's not immediately clear to me how to do this in a feed, however, as the same effective syntax with a made-up tag (-blarg in this case) gives me a 404 error.  If, on the other hand, I use the same syntax with a *valid* tag, then it works fine:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=-fonts&sort=newest

Comment: @cm2 Yeah... that unfortunately doesn't work. I was hoping `-untagged` would do, but it also 404s. Just picking the most obscure/least interesting tag is probably the best bet for the moment.

Answer (score 9):

I wasn’t quite satisfied with the situation, too (but actually because there are only the latest 30 active questions). So, I was attempted to put a feature-request onto Meta.SE. Luckily I did a search for rss-tagged questions first and found this recently asked and answered one: [How can I get more then 30 feed items?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126078/how-can-i-get-more-then-30-feed-items)

After a short try & (typing) error I found out, that this works very well:

http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/tex.stackexchange/questions?body=false&pagesize=100&sort=creation

(for RSS readers one should probably use “body=true”). As you can see on the [Stack Exchange API documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) there are lots of opportunities for other feeds, e.g. only for answers or only for comments or … The selection by tags works, too. The “pagesize=100” is the maximum and shows me today questions back to about 45 hours.

For meta.tex.SX it also works: http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/meta.tex.stackexchange/questions?body=false&pagesize=100&sort=creation

*If you find this useful, please upvote the original answer in Meta.SE as well, if possible for you.*