# SE contacts list / favourite members / "follow" members

Tags: feature-request, rss

I know there is no private message system nor "friendship" option inside SE Network but, is there something similar, like, for example, an option to mark some members as favourite ones?

Comment: We still like you even if we are not of your favorites. Come to the chat room and be properly friends with them instead of clicking strange buttons and faking it :P

Comment: :S My main use for that would be in fact to follow people I know in _real life_, not to take users in _fake life_, like those in the chat room, as properly friends.

Comment: Haha, nice counter. However, why would you follow your real friends online? Is there a trust problem ? :)

Comment: I think that this is status-bydesign. While friendships on the sites are welcomed, the site is not intended to encourage them actively this way. Asking, voting, commenting and answering are the goals of the site, and they should not be based on personal preferences, therefore the lack of any social networking features. At least that's how I see it. Nevertheless, @percusse has a point! :)

Comment: may be follow the members on their respective code repositories. make friends by following their code :)

Comment: @texenthusiast: Clemens and I do this, we stalk people on GitHub. `:)`

Comment: or come to TUG! :D Because really—how can you be sure we're all real people? For example, sometimes I just think egreg is a physical manifestation of `texdoc`. Totally plausible. Also, while work on it is slow, I intend to have this 'favorite' functionality built-in to [`stack-mode`](http://www.github.com/vermiculus/stack-mode), as it is not part of SE proper.

Answer (score 5):

There is a  `user feed` at the bottom right corner of a users profile page, which you can use with a feed syndication application to follow a user.

For example, I use OS X, and with it, a syndication app called [Monotony](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/monotony/id533978766?l=en&mt=12) which will relay the updates to OS X's built-in Notification Center.

You can find a lot of feeds for different things inside the StackExchange network – just look for the feed icon.
The feed icon looks like this

[image]

Related Links

[Useful StackApps and other User Scripts for TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2475/useful-stackapps-and-other-user-scripts-for-tex-sx/2491#2491)

[RSS feed for New questions?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/rss-feed-for-new-questions)